# What is the difference between sapience and sophonce?

Tags: terminology

The words [*sentient*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sentient) and [*sapient*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sapient) have fairly clear meanings, but the neologism [*sophont*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophont) appears to be a synonym of *sapient*. Yet in a number of fiction a kind of hierarchy is made between the three.

In a fair amount of science fiction, the word *sentient* is misused as a synonym of *sapient*. In fiction such as *Star Wars*, this is further mangled [into a distinction between](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sentience/Legends) "non-sentient" or "sub-sentient," "semi-sentient" and "fully sentient."

Initially I thought the *sentient*, *sapient* and *sophont* distinction was just a semantically correct version of the *Star Wars*-style of terminology. Yet fiction that uses this "correct" terminology, such as [Orion's Arm](http://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/480fdc506d995) or [The Eldraeverse](https://eldraeverse.com/2012/02/02/the-s-words-sentience-sapience-and-sophonce/), often has dramatically different definitions and ideas about cognition (such as sapience without sentience, which I have difficulty imagining).

Even sentience may even be quantified as a "[sentience quotient](http://www.rfreitas.com/Astro/Xenopsychology.htm)," unrelated to sapience or sophone, on which both plants and animals are measured. I don't know where I heard the idea, but I was initially under the impressions that plants were not sentient at all (by lacking nervous systems) until the quotient measured their sentience as much lower than animals.

I have no idea which distinction between *sapient* and *sophont* is correct, if any.

Comment: So, what parts of speech do the words represent.  Which one is a noun?

Comment: Frankly, since 'sophont' is a neologism in a very narrow field (sci-fi and not bio-psychology), I'd think this best answered by experts in that field, at scifi.SE, and not at english.SE (where 'sophont' is definitely not a word). I hesitate to have a migrate war though.

Comment: That link re sophont has this phrase: any species with language-level intelligence. Last time I looked, that is called a human being, which is the only species that is a speaking being.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't any.  "Sophont" is just another word used by some authors for the same thing.  It appears to have originated with Poul Anderson's *Trouble Twisters*.  See [Where did the term "sophont" originate?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181787/where-did-the-term-sophont-originate) for a discussion.

Answer (score -2):

In real life it is meta-philosophy. (Thinking about thinking, and recursive/nested/fractal-like thoughts,for example: thinking about how your type of thinking/personality has impacted how you talked and thought when you talked to someone earlier)
In hypothetical&fictional terms it's equivalent to having the ability to comprehend Forbidden knowledge without going insane or dying.
Also could be considered essentially relative omniscience, relative to how much you can understand and process at once rather than what you understand in total.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To put @Community’s comment in barer terms: this sounds like a lot of stuff you just personally made up. Can you demonstrate otherwise, in your answer?